# Foreground Service Notification issue

Tags: android, notifications, foreground-service

I have a foreground service and I build notifications through it. setColor is not working for all the devices even if they are running the same OS.

Anyone saw this problem before? Are there any hints on how to tackle it?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    createNotificationChannel();

    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(input);
    spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, input.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.addLine(spannable);

    Intent fullScreenIntent = CallStateObserver.launchCallScreenIntent(getApplicationContext(), "", null, null);
    PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), fullScreenIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 23 ? getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name):"")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setGroup("false")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call)
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
            .setColorized(true)
            .setUsesChronometer(true)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.accent))
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: can you share your notification code?

Comment: @Napster just added the code